# Multiple x axis - on top and botton with different data - android mpchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I would like to achieve the following using the bar chart. I went through the docs and I could not find an option to add x axis at the top of the bar chart and at the bottom of as well. So the dates would be at the bottom x axis and the day would be at the top. Is this possible at the moment?

Please let me know how I can achieve the following?

[image]

Comment: Buddy you can do it by exchanging ur axis like you can show two different Y-Axis on left and right but on x-axis I think u cant do this. Like on axis left you can have dates on right you have days and x axis u have values 250,500. And your will be horizontal

Comment: If you are interested in doing by that way ask me anytime I will help you out

Comment: Or you can do one more thing you can show M,T,W above bars instead of top axis. It can be done where bar ends at top of it you show your day

Comment: as M.Saad Lakhan said... one way would be a value renderer to display the days instead of the values above the bars (no extra axis label as you wish but would fullfill the job (: )

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but the design is specified this way and it can't be changed and its needs to be at the top. If there was a way to display values above the axis instead of above the bar, that would be good also